# Any Recent Experience with WPEngine and CiviCRM?

Tags: hosting, hosting-providers

Long story short, admins insist on using WPEngine, I explained we would want to explore other options and I can't guarantee it will work flawlessly. I know there are posts from years ago about successfully hosting CiviCRM on Wordpress using WPEngine, but does that still apply in 2022? Any other reasons to be concerned?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth checking if they have PHP Intl available which is a core requirement.

Flywheel, who are owned by WpEngine, don't & have no plans to add it.

Comment: They do have PHP Intl